# Append query string to iframe source

Tags: jquery

I've got a page with several iframes that are added by the end user via a cms. I need to append a query string (exactly the same to all iframes) to the end of the iframe source and am stuck on how to proceed.

My current code is here where .frame-wrap is a container around all iframes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hideLinkHeader = '?hideLink=true&hideHeader=true';
    var url = cannot figure out how to set this for each iframe

    $('.frame-wrap').find('iframe').attr('src', url + hideLinkHeader);

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `url` supposed to be? The original source?

Comment: @Frayt yes the original url does not change (it's different for each iframe). I need to append the query string to each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work if I'm understanding your issue correctly

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var hideLinkHeader = '?hideLink=true&hideHeader=true';

//Loop through every iframe in .frame-wrap
$.each($('.frame-wrap').find('iframe'), function(index, i)
{
    //set url equal to this iteration's iframe's src
    var url = $(i).attr('src');

   //set this iteration's iframe's src equal to url plus the hideLinkHeader global variable
   $(i).attr('src', url + hideLinkHeader);

});
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srmzuheb/1/